# Appending and crossfade images dynamically with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is what I have now:

```
<div id="nhs_BasicSearchBox">
    <img src="img1.jpg" />
    <img src="img2.jpg" />
</div>
```

but what I really want to do is to add the images dynamically:

```
<div id="nhs_BasicSearchBox"></div>
```

and this my jquery:

```
$('img').hide();

function animg() {
    $("#nhs_BasicSearchBox img").first().appendTo('#nhs_BasicSearchBox').fadeOut(1500);
    $("#nhs_BasicSearchBox img").first().fadeIn(1500);
    setTimeout(animg, 6000);
}
animg();
```

I'm a bit lost. Any help? [This is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/3rdxqz66/5/). Thanks.

Comment: Well, is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/3rdxqz66/6/) what you are talking about?

Comment: @Regent please don't post answers in comments, the question will remain unanswered...

Comment: @Regent [please read](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272940/2333214)

Comment: @TJ I have read this and some other related questions in Meta. Well, I agree that there are drawbacks in lefting the correct answer in comments (when there are no correct answers). I'll try to add them as answers in future (of course, if it will turn out to be correct answer in comments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create array of images' links and then append new `<img>`s with these links as `src` to container using `for` loop:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/3rdxqz66/6/).

```
var imageLinks = ["link1", "link2"];

var container = $("#nhs_BasicSearchBox");
for (var i = 0; i < imageLinks.length; i++)
{
    container.append($('<img>', { src: imageLinks[i] }));
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Regent the <img> is being appended to the container but I don't understand the { src: ..... }

Comment: @Labanino It is setting of `<img>`'s `src` attribute. The whole line equals to `container.append($('<img src="' + imageLinks[i] + '">'));`, but looks more simple/elegant. You can also set another attributes of newly created element: for example, also `alt`: `{ src: imageLinks[i], alt: "my_text" }`

Comment: Nice, '+' is more intuitive than '{ }'. Thank you very much.

Comment: container.append($('<img src="' + imageLinks[i] + '" alt="">')); worked for me.

Comment: @Labanino You're welcome. Yes, it's more intuitive, but with `{}` code looks cleaner. In different situations one or another way is more suitable.